# VNC Viewer with clipboard sync

Tags: macbook-pro, remote-desktop

I need to connect to Ubuntu Vinegar VNC and Windows UltraVNC.  I can't find one that sync's the clipboard so I can past from my Macbook to the others OS.  It works fine Windows to Ubuntu and vise versa so the VNC servers are fine.

A low cost solution would be preferred as my countries currency is a quarter of the value of the US$.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jollys Fast VNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html)

It attempts to keep the clipboards in sync and for the most part it does a very good job of it. Not all objects copied to the clipboard on one machine can be used on another though. For example: copying a file the clipboard just puts a lean file object in the clipboard which has no parallel on the remote machine.

But for text and such it works great.

There's a free trial (that continually renews itself) and [you can buy it in the MAS as well for not a lot of money](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/jollysfastvnc-pro/id406781941?mt=12) (there's [a "home" version for even less](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/jollysfastvnc-home/id406781929?mt=12)).

[image]

Comment: I can't find any way to get remote content (e.g. plain text) into the local clipboard. Is this a Mac OS 10.9 related problem?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I can't say. Have to tried contact the developer?

Comment: Not yet. I'm just trying to find some Mac VNC client that can do this. Seems like an important and fairly basic feature to me, but I haven't found a way to do this in either Chicken VNC or Jollys Fast VNC, and it's not completely clear to me if they are supposed to support this feature.

Comment: Jollys Fast VNC should do this. It's one of it's big selling points.

Comment: OK, thanks. Can't find an explicit feature for this in Jollys Fast VNC, but perhaps I should just be able to use regular copy command on the remote computer, and regular paste command locally. In that case, it's probably a Mac OS 10.9 issue.

Answer (score -1):

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx?cdsplit=C) supports Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux, and has great support for remote actions, file transfers, and native clipboard exchanges.  I've never used TV for clipboards with remote Linux systems but it's definitely been better than any VNC solutions I've used.  Free for personal use.